# Using tidyr complete() with column names specified in variables

Tags: r, tidyr

I am having trouble using the `tidyr::complete()` function with column names as variables.

The built-in example works as expected:

```
df <- data_frame(
 group = c(1:2, 1),
 item_id = c(1:2, 2),
 item_name = c("a", "b", "b"),
 value1 = 1:3,
 value2 = 4:6
)

df %>% complete(group, nesting(item_id, item_name))
```

However, when I try to provide the column names as character strings, it produces an error.

```
gr="group"
id="item_id"
name="item_name"
df %>% complete_(gr, nesting_(id, name),fill = list(NA))
```

Comment: According to the source code, `nesting_` only takes one argument (a list).

Comment: Is it supposed to throw an arrow, I wonder?

Comment: @David Arenburg: It does when fill = list(NA) is missing

Comment: Welp, I know that `tidyr` can do some stuff, but throwing arrows at you is an interesting feature

Comment: I've got this far, but haven't got `complete_` to work yet: `df %>% complete(group, nesting_(setNames(list(.[[id]], .[[name]]), c(id, name))))` Also, it's ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a bug that `complete_` can't work with data.frames or list columns like `complete` can, but here's a workaround using `unite_` and `separate` to simulate `nesting`:

```
df %>% unite_('id_name', c(id, name)) %>% 
    complete_(c(gr, 'id_name')) %>% 
    separate(id_name, c(id, name))

## # A tibble: 4 × 5
##   group item_id item_name value1 value2
## * <dbl>   <chr>     <chr>  <int>  <int>
## 1     1       1         a      1      4
## 2     1       2         b      3      6
## 3     2       1         a     NA     NA
## 4     2       2         b      2      5
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @alistaire this works fine for small data frames. When I try the pattern on a large object I get an Warning message: Too many values at 691968 locations: ... and the function doesn't complete the entire data frame

Comment: That error is usually because other separator characters already exist in the data, and so it's getting split too many times. The `sep` parameter of `separate` defaults to any non-alphanumeric characters, but you can limit it to the separator used by `unite` (`_` by default) by adding `sep = '_'`.

Comment: You're right. that was actually the case in my data set. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Even a little more simply, `df %>% complete(!!!syms(gr), nesting(!!!syms(id), !!!syms(name)))` now gets it done in tidyr 1.0.2

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  By the way, in this use case, just two exclamation marks would suffice, e.g. `!!sym(gr)` rather than `!!!syms(gr)` as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61180201/triple-exclamation-marks-on-r.

Comment: It does not work with unquoted names

Comment: For unquoted, do `!!sym(rlang::enexpr(col))`

Answer (score 2):

Now that `tidyr` has adopted tidy evaluation, the underscore variants (i.e. `complete_`) have been deprecated since their behavior can be handled by the standard variants (`complete`).

However, `complete`, `crossing` and `nesting` use data-masking, so the way to convert variables into names is via the `.data[[var]]` pronoun (per [the docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/dev/articles/programming.html#data-masking)), so your case becomes:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(tidyr)
)

df <- data.frame(
  group = c(1:2, 1),
  item_id = c(1:2, 2),
  item_name = c("a", "b", "b"),
  value1 = 1:3,
  value2 = 4:6
)

gr <- "group"
id <- "item_id"
name <- "item_name"

df %>% complete(
  .data[[gr]],
  nesting(.data[[id]],
          .data[[name]])
)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   group item_id item_name value1 value2
#>   <dbl>   <dbl> <fct>      <int>  <int>
#> 1     1       1 a              1      4
#> 2     1       2 b              3      6
#> 3     2       1 a             NA     NA
#> 4     2       2 b              2      5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Not very elegant, but it gets the job done.

Comment: With `tidyr` v1.2.0, this results in: Error in `.data[["item_id"]]`:
! Column `item_id` not found in `.data`.