# Inserting a new row without specifying column names in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to insert a row into my dataframe but I don't want to write the columns names because that make the code too wordy. This is what I know it works:

```
# add_row ---------------------------------
df <- tibble(x = 1:3, y = 3:1)

df %>% add_row(x = 4, y = 0, .before = 3)
 A tibble: 4 x 2
       x     y
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     3
 2     2     2
 3     4     0
 4     3     1
```

And this is what I wish it worked but it doesn't:

```
df %>% add_row(c(4,0), .before = 3)
```

Does anyone know if there is another way for doing that with dplyr?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `add_row` requires name-value pairs but if you don't want to mention them explicitly you can automate the creation of it.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% add_row(!!!setNames(c(4, 0), names(.)), .before = 3)

#      x     y
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     3
#2     2     2
#3     4     0
#4     3     1
```

Comment: so triple bang operator is doing here the job of automating it?

Comment: That is correct. Honestly, I was expecting `!!` to work but it does not work.

Comment: I just read your [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61180370/2884859) on another question about this big bang operator.  +1. :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R`

```
rbind(df, c(4, 0))[c(1, 2, 4, 3),]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bind_rows(
  tibble(x = 1:3, y = 3:1),
  c(x = 4, y = 0)
)
```

Output:

```
x     y
<dbl> <dbl>
  1     1     3
2     2     2
3     3     1
4     4     0
```