# How to write a simple for loop that will populate a new column based on values in an old column, using key-value pairs?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop

I'm working with data that look like this:

| label |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |

I have a key-value index I've created (with code like that below) to use in creating a new column based on this existing column.

```
values <- c("word1", "word2", "word3")
keys <- c("a", "b", "c")
index <- setNames(as.list(values), keys)
```

With this index made, I was expecting to be able to create a new column with a simple one line for loop, like below.

```
df$newcol <- for (x in df$label){index$x}
```

This code doesn't seem to produce any change in my dataframe at all, though. What am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `dplyr::recode`:

```
df$newcol <- dplyr::recode(df$label, !!!index)
```

Output:

```
> df
  label newcol
1     a  word1
2     b  word2
3     c  word3
>
```

Comment: Love the tidyverse solution, thank you! If possible, could you explain more what the logic behind !!!index is?

Comment: @nlplearner `!!!` unpacks the values into separate arguments, whereas `recode` requires a first sequence, then multiple values for the ones to map, like `dplyr::recode(x, value1, value2, ... , value100)`, so if I don't use `!!!`, it would be treated as `dplyr::recode(x, values)`. Which would treat the second vector as a value, here is the official documentation on this function: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/recode

Comment: @nlplearner More about the triple exclamation marks here: [Triple exclamation marks on R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61180201)

Answer (score 1):

Try check `for (x in df$label){print(index$x)}`.

It will return

```
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Instead of `$` inside function, try using `[]` to call some values.
And, make a new vector first then append it to `df$newcol` will work.

```
newcol <- c()
for (x in df$label){
  newcol <- c(newcol, index[x])
  }
df$newcol <- newcol
df

  label newcol
1     a  word1
2     b  word2
3     c  word3
```

Or, little change to `for` loop

```
for (x in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$newcol[x] <- index[df$label[x]]
}
df

  label newcol
1     a  word1
2     b  word2
3     c  word3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a data frame rather than a list index. Then using `match()`.

```
index <- data.frame(values, keys)
df$newcol <- index[match(df$label, index$keys), 'values']
df
#   label newcol
# 1     a  word1
# 2     b  word2
# 3     c  word3
# 4     a  word1
# 5     b  word2
# 6     c  word3
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- data.frame(label=letters[c(1:3, 1:3)])

index <- structure(list(values = c("word1", "word2", "word3"), keys = c("a", 
"b", "c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```