# rename variables with variable labels in R

Tags: r, labelled

I am forever working with collaborators in SPSS and STata so clear variable labels are really important to communiate what has been done to any given variable and what it records.

How do I rename variables with their variable labels most efficiently in a tidyverse context.
I can do this, but it seems very unwieldy.

```
var1<-rnorm(100)
var2<-rnorm(100)
var3<-rnorm(100)
group_var<-sample(c("A", "B"), size=100, replace=T)
other_var1<-rnorm(100)
other_var2<-rnorm(100)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2, var3, group_var, other_var1, other_var2)
library(labelled)
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  set_variable_labels(var1="Measure 1", 
                      var2="Measure 2",
                      var3="Measure 3",
                        group_var="Grouping Variable")->df


#Store variable labels
df %>% 
  select(starts_with("var")) %>% 
  var_label() %>% 
  unlist()->variable_labels
variable_labels<-data.frame(name=names(variable_labels), labels=variable_labels)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(var1:var3) %>% 
  left_join(., variable_labels, by="name")
```

Is there a way to make the `rename_with` function work here?
This does not do it.

```
df %>% 
  rename_with(., function(x) var_label(x),.cols=var1:var3)
```

Comment: I am confused about the last part. What are you trying to do with the `rename_with()` - rename the variables in `df` to their corresponding label, so that `var1` becomes `Measure 1`?

Comment: Note that you can get the `variable_labels` data set with `labelled::look_for()`.

Answer (score 6):

We could use `!!!` with `rename` on a named list or vector created from `variable_labels` dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df <- df %>% 
   rename(!!! deframe(variable_labels[2:1]))
```

-Check the names

```
> names(df)
[1] "Measure 1"  "Measure 2"  "Measure 3"  "group_var"  "other_var1" "other_var2"
```

---

Or if we want to use `rename_with`

```
df <- df %>%
  rename_with(~ variable_labels$labels, 
      .cols = variable_labels$name)
```

---

The reason `var_label` is not working is because it is looking for the value of the columns and not the column names i.e. according to `?var_label`

> x - a vector or a data.frame

```
var_label("var1")
NULL
```

whereas

```
> var_label(df$var1)
[1] "Measure 1"
```

If we dig the function `rename_with.data.frame` it would be more evident

```
getAnywhere('rename_with.data.frame')
function (.data, .fn, .cols = everything(), ...) 
{
    .fn <- as_function(.fn)
    cols <- tidyselect::eval_select(enquo(.cols), .data)
    names <- names(.data)
    names[cols] <- .fn(names[cols], ...)
    names <- vec_as_names(names, repair = "check_unique")
    set_names(.data, names)
}
```

i.e. the `.fn` or the lambda function is applied on the column names.  Thus, when we use `var_label`, it require data.frame or vector and it fails

-added print statements in a modified function

```
rename_with_mod <- function (.data, .fn, .cols = everything(), ...) 
{
   
    cols <- tidyselect::eval_select(enquo(.cols), .data)
    print("cols")
    print(cols)
    names <- names(.data)
    print("names")
    print(names)
    .fn <- rlang::as_function(.fn)
    print(names[cols])
    .fn(names[cols], ...)
    
}
```

-Testing

```
 # lambda function to return the column name
 > df %>% 
  + rename_with_mod(~ .x, .cols=var1:var3)
[1] "cols"
var1 var2 var3 
   1    2    3 
[1] "names"
[1] "var1"       "var2"       "var3"       "group_var"  "other_var1" "other_var2"
[1] "var1" "var2" "var3"
[1] "var1" "var2" "var3"
# lambda function where we apply the var_label - returns NULL
> df %>% 
+   rename_with_mod(~ var_label(.x), .cols=var1:var3)
[1] "cols"
var1 var2 var3 
   1    2    3 
[1] "names"
[1] "var1"       "var2"       "var3"       "group_var"  "other_var1" "other_var2"
[1] "var1" "var2" "var3"
NULL
```

Comment: This seems great but could you explain what the `!!!` is doing?

Comment: @SamR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61180201/triple-exclamation-marks-on-r

Comment: @SamR We are passing a named vector( or named list) and `!!!` is a splice operator

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the attributes directly:

```r
colnames(data) <- sapply(data, function(x) attr(x, "label"))
```

Or if you prefer `var_label` and `rename_with` (beware though that there is no datamasking available here, thus `data`, not `.data`):

```r
data |> 
  rename_with(function(x) sapply(x, function(y) var_label(data[[y]])))
```

Example with labelled `haven` `iris` data:

```r
library(haven)

> path <- system.file("examples", "iris.dta", package = "haven")
> data <- read_dta(path)
> data
# A tibble: 150 × 5
   sepallength sepalwidth petallength petalwidth species
         <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>  
 1        5.10       3.5         1.40      0.200 setosa 
 2        4.90       3           1.40      0.200 setosa 
 3        4.70       3.20        1.30      0.200 setosa 
 4        4.60       3.10        1.5       0.200 setosa 
 5        5          3.60        1.40      0.200 setosa 
 6        5.40       3.90        1.70      0.400 setosa 
 7        4.60       3.40        1.40      0.300 setosa 
 8        5          3.40        1.5       0.200 setosa 
 9        4.40       2.90        1.40      0.200 setosa 
10        4.90       3.10        1.5       0.100 setosa 
# … with 140 more rows
> colnames(data) <- sapply(data, function(x) attr(x, "label"))
> data
# A tibble: 150 × 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>  
 1         5.10        3.5          1.40       0.200 setosa 
 2         4.90        3            1.40       0.200 setosa 
 3         4.70        3.20         1.30       0.200 setosa 
 4         4.60        3.10         1.5        0.200 setosa 
 5         5           3.60         1.40       0.200 setosa 
 6         5.40        3.90         1.70       0.400 setosa 
 7         4.60        3.40         1.40       0.300 setosa 
 8         5           3.40         1.5        0.200 setosa 
 9         4.40        2.90         1.40       0.200 setosa 
10         4.90        3.10         1.5        0.100 setosa 
# … with 140 more rows
```

Consider using `janitor::make_clean_names` afterwards to make life easier for yourself.

Comment: How so harre? Part of the problem is that I'm doing the data cleaning for collaborators who work only in SPSS and Stata. I'm not inclined to change original variable names. But if you have suggestions for improved workflow, I'm all ears.

Comment: Variable labels can contain e.g. spaces and other characters that are horrible to work with in R if you use them directly as column names.

Comment: In that use case it would probably be better keeping the variable names and labels separate and save into `.dta` or `.sav` preserving both.